# Custom widget not working as expected - GetX package Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I have created a custom widget to create a button as in the below image.
[image]

The Stages option works fine but when I toggle to the Bids List option, I get an output like below image.

[image]

Why is the stages coming in grey color when I select the Bids List Option but the vice versa works fine? Can anyone correct it? I am using GetX in my project.

> SelectionOptionButton.dart

```
class SelectOptionButton extends StatelessWidget {
  SelectOptionButton({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final grey = const Color.fromARGB(50, 158, 158, 158);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(color: Color(0xffc8a2c8) // Color(0xffE0E0E0),
                ), //  Color.fromARGB(165, 158, 158, 158)),
            BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.white, // Color.fromARGB(21, 158, 158, 158),
                spreadRadius: -1.0,
                blurRadius: 15.0)
          ], //color: grey,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5))),
      padding:
          const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.05, bottom: 0.05, left: 7, right: 7),
      child: Row(children: [
        SpecificButton(
            isFirstOptionSelected: true, buttonName: 'Stages', id: 1),
        SpecificButton(
            isFirstOptionSelected: false, buttonName: 'Bids List', id: 2),
      ]),
    );
  }
}

class SpecificButton extends StatelessWidget {
  SpecificButton(
      {Key? key,
      required this.isFirstOptionSelected,
      required this.buttonName,
      required this.id})
      : super(key: key);
  int id;
  bool isFirstOptionSelected;
  String buttonName;

  final SelectOptionButtonController _selectOptionButtonController =
      Get.put(SelectOptionButtonController());
  final grey = Color.fromARGB(23, 243, 243, 243);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Obx(
      () => Expanded(
          child: ElevatedButton(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                elevation: isFirstOptionSelected ? 1.5 : 0, //1.5:0,
                backgroundColor: isFirstOptionSelected
                    ? _selectOptionButtonController.isFirstOptionSelected.value
                        ? Colors.white
                        : Colors.transparent //grey
                    : !_selectOptionButtonController.isFirstOptionSelected.value
                        ? Colors.white
                        : Colors.transparent, //grey,
                primary: isFirstOptionSelected
                    ? _selectOptionButtonController.isFirstOptionSelected.value
                        ? MyColors.primaryGradient
                        : Colors.black
                    : !_selectOptionButtonController.isFirstOptionSelected.value
                        ? MyColors.primaryGradient
                        : Colors.black,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                (id == 1 &&
                            _selectOptionButtonController
                                    .isFirstOptionSelected.value ==
                                true) ||
                        (id == 2 &&
                            _selectOptionButtonController
                                    .isFirstOptionSelected.value ==
                                false)
                    ? null
                    : _selectOptionButtonController.changeSelected();
              },
              child: Text(
                buttonName,
                style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'HelveticaBold'),
              ))),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the respective controller

```
class SelectOptionButtonController extends GetxController {
  var isFirstOptionSelected = true.obs;

  void changeSelected() {
    isFirstOptionSelected.value = !isFirstOptionSelected.value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `Obx()` for reflect changes

```
Obx(() => Row(children: [
        SpecificButton(
            isFirstOptionSelected: true, buttonName: 'Stages', id: 1),
        SpecificButton(
            isFirstOptionSelected: false, buttonName: 'Bids List', id: 2),
      ]),)
```

Comment: Wrapping the container widget with Obx() is not helping. My question is I have given BoxDecoration to the entire container. Row is the child of the container. Meaning no matter which button is selected, the inner shadow effect must appear by default because of the code I've written. But the inner shadow effect appears only for one half of the container and not the other. Why is it so?

Answer (score 0):

their are two type to change value which is also derive from its state
sample

```
class SelectOptionButtonController extends GetxController {
  var isFirstOptionSelected = true.obs;

  void changeSelected() {
    /// this part lack below called update();
    isFirstOptionSelected.value = !isFirstOptionSelected.value;
    update(); /// try add this to change the value good to use on this is GetBuilder
    /// or
    /// isFirstOptionSelected(!isFirstOptionSelected.value);
    /// changing value for Obx
   }
}
```

to change it state

```
return Obx(()
  => Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(color: Color(0xffc8a2c8) // Color(0xffE0E0E0),
                ), //  Color.fromARGB(165, 158, 158, 158)),
            BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.white, // Color.fromARGB(21, 158, 158, 158),
                spreadRadius: -1.0,
                blurRadius: 15.0)
          ], //color: grey,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5))),
      padding:
          const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.05, bottom: 0.05, left: 7, right: 7),
      child: Row(children: [
        SpecificButton(
            isFirstOptionSelected: controller.isFirstOptionSelected.isTrue, buttonName: 'Stages', id: 1),
        SpecificButton(
            isFirstOptionSelected: controller.isFirstOptionSelected.isFalse, buttonName: 'Bids List', id: 2),
      ]),
    );
  );
```

try it.

Comment: Wrapping the container widget with Obx() is not helping. My question is I have given BoxDecoration to the entire container. Row is the child of the container. Meaning no matter which button is selected, the inner shadow effect must appear by default because of the code I've written. But the inner shadow effect appears only for one half of the container and not the other. Why is it so?

Answer (score 0):

do just replace your method to following method ,

```
void changeSelected() {
isFirstOptionSelected.value =! isFirstOptionSelected.value; }
```